# ADO returns wrong order of magnitude

Tags: vba, ado, firebird

i'm writing a VBA macro for Excel 2003. I'm importing various data from a sql database to the Excel sheets.

I tried two ways to do that:

1. `QueryTables.Add(...)`
2. with ADO

I was in favour of ADO, because it seemed to be the 'better' or 'cleaner" solution.

Everything worked well until i tried to get a numeric value with ADO out of the database. Instead of returning the value `1842,47078` it returned `0,01842`. (just to show what i mean)

Strange thing is: when i try it with `QueryTables.Add(...)` i get the right value.

I have totally no clue why this happens, searched the internet for a solution but didn't found anything. It just happens with numeric values. If i get a string from the database everything is fine.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Driver is Firebird/InterBase(r) driver connecting with ODBC.
Here is a little example how i do things:

```
    'ADO solution = wrong value
    With adoConnection
      .Provider = "MSDASQL"
      sConnection = "ODBC;DSN=ABC;Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=blaName.gdb;"
      ConnectionString = sConnection
      .Open
    End With
    SQL_Import = "SELECT A.PRICE AS ""Price"" FROM TABLE A WHERE A.KEY ='x1234' "
    adoRecordset.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
    adoRecordset.Open SQL_Import
    varSol = adoRecordset.Fields("Price")
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).Value = varSol
    adoRecordset.Close
    adoRecordset.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    adoConnection.Close
    'QueryTables solution = right value
    Set QueryTbl = Sheets(3).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConnection, Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(1, 2))
    With QueryTbl
        .CommandText = SQL_Import
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete
    End With
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Update:

- I got it working somehow, but i don't know what was wrong.
- I get the right results if i use the query `SELECT Price as numeric(15, 2)...`.
- Strange thing is that i tried the whole thing with C# on my computer and it worked without any problems. So the error seems to be caused by anything in Excel and/or VBA.

Comment: I would place a break after the recordset is returned and test to see if the correct value is returned into the recordset, if its not, there could be something wrong with how the connection is setup.  If the value shows correct in the recordset, could be an error passing the data out of the recordset.  I'm not familiar with firebird connections, so I'm not much help there.

Comment: In your first With...End With block you're missing the dot on ConnectionString, so it's likely you're not actually setting that property. Don't know if that's relevant to what you're seeing.

Comment: It's .ConnectionString in the actual code. Just did it wrong, when i wrote this example. And I stopped the macro and checked the recordset. The value is already wrong when it's return to the recordset. So it really seems to be a problem with the connection. Perhaps the Provider?

Comment: Is `varSol` a `Variant` as the prefix implies? Is it any different if you write `varSol = CStr(adoRecordset.Fields("Price"))` and then check the value of `varSol`?

Comment: Yes it is a Variant, but using your code gives the same result as above. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

**Try applying a NumberFormat to the cell**

```
varSol = adoRecordset.Fields("Price") 
Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "###0,#######0" 
Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).Value = varSol
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about firebird but it sounds like the column in question is in Money or Currency type (what ADO calls adCurrency) and you haven't told ADO this, so it's not converting it appropriately.

Look at adoRecordset.Fields("Price").Type and I'll bet you'll see that it's adCurrency or the like.

Comment: The adoRecordset.Fields("Price").Type is 'adNumeric'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really **what** the problem is/was, but i have a solution.
If i alter my SQL string to

```
SQL_Import = "SELECT A.PRICE*1  FROM TABLE A WHERE A.KEY ='x1234' "
```

everything works as expected and i get the right result.

So my solution is multiplying with one or adding zero.

Comment: You're causing an implicit type conversion through the arithmetic operation -- `A.PRICE` is being CAST as a type which can be combined with the `*1` or `+0`. It's very similar to the effect of `SELECT Price as numeric(15, 2)...`