# Ado returning wrong Values for adNumeric(21,6) via ODBC

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, odbc, ado

I am getting weird return Values from my ADO Recordset.

I tried it in VBA, VB and C++, but everytime i get the same weird and wrong values.

The Data is stored in our ERP System as `Dec(21,6)`, this information is passed to ADO correct `(adNumeric, Precision 21, Scale 6)`.

I am connecting to the DB via ODBC and ADO, the connection works fine and `varChar`, `Date` and other formats are just passed fine, only the `dec(21,6)` values are showing this weird result.

However, if i run a MS Query, it returns the correct Values, so i think i am missing some settings, but can atm not figure out which ones ...

I already tried to `cast`/`convert` the values, but this is not supported by the ODBC.
I wrote an VB and an C++ Program and received the same wrong values.

Here is my simple VBA Code for testing:

```
        Sub test()
Dim ADOODBCConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim ADOODBCConnectionString As String
Dim ADOODBCRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim TestString As String
Dim TestVariant As Variant

ADOODBCConnectionString = "DSN=myDSN" 'DSN Name
Set ADOODBCConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set ADOODBCRS = New ADODB.Recordset
ADOODBCRS.Source = "SELECT quantity_amount FROM ENTITY.app_production_ProductionOrder WHERE type_BK ='101' AND number ='PA00041825';" 

ADOODBCConnection.Open ADOODBCConnectionString
ADOODBCRS.ActiveConnection = ADOODBCConnection
ADOODBCRS.Open
'wrong Values are already in the recordset
TestString = ADOODBCRS.Fields(0).Value    'wrong Value
TestVar = ADOODBCRS.Fields(0).Value       'wrong ValueUrsprungspost

ADOODBCRS.Close
ADOODBCConnection.Close

End Sub
```

Here are some expected and some received values:

```
Expected   Received
1          -13511005043556401
2          -13511005043556402 
3          -13511005043556403
7          -13511005043556407 
8          -13511005043556408 
9          -13511005043556409 
10         -885457226534512230449 
500        -885456663593148743733
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818220/ado-returns-wrong-order-of-magnitude?rq=1) might be similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found that ADO is returning the wrong Values, but not .NET ODBC, so i switched from Excel to VB and used .NET ODBC (system.data.odbc).

I am still confused, why this behaves the way it does, but it seems to be in the configuration of ADO or our ODBC, both i can not change, so i use an alternative.

**Long story short: ADO gets wrong values, .NET ODBC gets the correct ones**